# Increasing writing speed to file inside a for-loop for large files

Tags: performance, python-3.x, file, iteration

I have a .csv file containing 100 millions records, I would to create multiple files from this file, after certain condition satisfied in each line, I came to this code below, but it is slow, I think, it is due the fact the a file is opened and closed in each iteration.
The result is many files renamed after countries, each file has inside the correspondant line from the large file.
Is there any approach or method that can get rid of this problem and increase the speed?

```
import csv

with open('stats.csv','r', encoding = 'utf-8') as inf, open('stats_failed.txt', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8', newline = '') as failed_ouf:
    csr = csv.reader(inf)
    for i, record in enumerate(csr):
        try:
            country = record[3]
            #because some country have these characters, invalid for file renaming
            if '/' in country:
                country = country.replace('/','_SLASH_')
            elif '\\' in country:
                country = country.replace('\\','_BACKSLASH_')
            
            #pop the country because irrelevant since the file has its name
            record.pop(3)

            with open(country, 'a', encoding = 'utf-8', newline = '') as output:
                csw = csv.writer(output)
                csw.writerow(record)
            
                #just for tracking
                if i % 100_000 == 0:
                    print(i)
                    output.flush()
        except:
            failed_csw = csv.writer(failed_ouf)
            failed_csw.writerow(record)
```

**EDITED**
To those who asked:
It looks like this:

```
col1,col2,country,mod1,code,mod2
\N,\N,Germany,C510,\N,C510
\N,\N,"China, Taipei",C25C,\N,C25C
\N,\N,Italy,GLF5,\N,GLF5
\N,\N,France,C25B,\N,C25B
\N,\N,Germany,C525,\N,C525
\N,\N,Turkey,PC12,\N,PC12
\N,\N,Germany,C680,\N,C680
\N,\N,Germany,GL5T,\N,GL5T
\N,\N,Germany,C25B,\N,C25B
\N,\N,Italy,GLF4,\N,GLF4
\N,\N,France,CRJ2,\N,CRJ2
\N,\N,Palestine,G280,\N,G280
\N,\N,Slovakia,C525,\N,C525
....
\N,\N,United States,E55P,\N,E55P
\N,\N,Russia,C56X,\N,C56X
```

**EDITED2**
If it is relevant, the size is about 4 GB

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the number of distinct *countries*?

Comment: Can you show some example input rows?

Comment: Does your input CSV file have a header? Can you show it?

Comment: @Reinderien, yes but I can skip it with i > 0 then do something, or letting it wrote to a file then delete it, it is only one line

Comment: @greybeard, yes! the countries are maximal distinct 260

Comment: @Reinderien,  the csv file is comma separated, with double quotation as quoting when quoting is necessary.
All columns are of type String with maximal length no more than 16 except countries.
If no data in a cell, then there is "\N" literally.
I added an example to my question.

Comment: I had an idea but I don't know if it is pratical, or allowed by windows OS or python.
Something like this:
with open(ctry1), open(ctry2), ..., open(ctry260)
But the problem is, long file open series (even it is allowed in OS) and I dont have all names of countries in a list, due to some typos in original file, or how are they written exactly

Comment: I tried to do my last idea as in the comment above but as expected, there is limit:
I got: "SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks"
Because python restrict it to 20

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: `"China, Taipei"` looks like it may be required to be handled as a list of aliases. (geographically and politically disputable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slow for a lot of reasons:

- It's Python
- The data-processing operations are non-vectorized
- There's one file open/write/close per row!

So delete your code and use Pandas, which is written in part in C and has Python FFI. 4 GB should fit into the working memory of most modern computers so you don't need to be clever with segmentation, etc.

I'm sure most other programs would sooner expect a blank `,,` CSV record to mean "nothing" than `\N`, so tell Pandas to load the latter as a NaN.

Your list of incompatible characters (at least on Windows) for filesystems is not complete. Also: since you're removing those characters from the filename, are you sure it's such a good idea to drop the original country string from the data?

Never bare `try`/`except`.

### Suggested

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('stats.csv', na_values=r'\N')

df['filename'] = df.country.str.replace(r'[^,\w_.)( -]+', '_', regex=True) + '.csv'

for filename, group in df.groupby('filename'):
    group.drop('filename', axis=1).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

```
col1,col2,country,mod1,code,mod2
,,"China, Taipei",C25C,,C25C
```

Comment: Thanks., with pandas it was a good idea since it is in C, but I splited my large file into four parts, then with pandas and at the end, merging same name files with pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Non-trivial source code deserves documentation.
Define a function, including a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).

My crystal ball shows killing speed is not (yet) writing, but opening files and creating CSV writers.

Create `failed_csv` upfront, once, using `with`.

> If `csvfile` is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''` [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3)

If you don't need to keep the order of records for any given country, you can handle spelling errors (or multiple names for the same country - UK, GB?) later concatenating files.
Alternatively, canonicalise country names before,
or create a dict from name to canonicalised name/file to use here:

Create a dict from country name to open CSV writer.